# Firebase on mobile how to authenticate call to cloud function?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase with my React Native app, and I only have anonymous login enabled.

I am trying to call a `Cloud Function` from the app, but not using the `firebase` SDK. Instead I want to call it with `axios`. When I pass the token grabbed from my `firebase` user as a Bearer token, I get back a 401 Unauthorized.

However, the request goes through if I copy the token I get from the CLI with `gcloud auth print-identity-token`.

How can I grab/setup a valid token that I could pass to the Cloud Function? Any relevant doc would be appreciated.

Im trying to call the function using a `onRequest`:

```
await axios.post(CLOUD_FUNC_URL, payload, {
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN}`,
  },
});
```

I am either grabbing the token from `gcloud CLI` (works) but the one from `await auth().currentUser?.getIdToken();` does not.

Comment: Can you update your question with your Axios request once and also what type of Cloud function are you using ? `onCall()` or `onRequest()` is using from Firebase? Also how are you generating the token that reutrns 401?  Maybe the function is not public for users but your token (perhaps from owner account) is allowing to?

Comment: Can you go to [Cloud Functions console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions), open details of that function and check "permissions"? Do you have `allUsers` principal with the role `Cloud Functions Invoker` ? Can you share a screenshot of that (blur out any credentials other than allUsers)?

Comment: Brilliant, that was it. Thank you. Please post your answer below and I will approve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function must be private (requires authentication) by default. It works with your token (`gcloud auth print-identity-token`) because you may be the owner of the project. You can go to [Cloud Functions console](https://console.cloud.google.com/functions) and add a principal `allUsers` with `Cloud Functions Invoker` role so it can be invoked by everyone.